# Express - Edit HTML before serving as static server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Before I call `expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../frontend/dist')));` I need to modify the html-code. What I basically need to do is inserting meta tags in two middleware functions. I figured out how to do this. But with my solution I call a middleware-functions inside another one.

### app.js

```
let frontend = await fs
  .readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/../frontend/dist/index.html'))
  .toString('utf8');

expressApp.use((req, res, next) => {
  //...
  frontend = frontend.replace(
    '<meta device="ABC" />',
    '<head><meta device="' + deviceId + '"/>'
  );
  next();
});

expressApp.use((req, res, next) => {
  const language = req.get('language') || 'en_GB';
  logger.info('language:' + language);
  this._languageModule.setLanguage(language);
  frontend = this._languageModule.insertSIDs(frontend);
  logger.info(frontend);
  expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../frontend/dist'))); // nested middleware function
  next();
});

/** set up all the express routes **/
expressApp.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(frontend);
});
```

### Edit

If I don't call `expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../frontend/dist')));` nested - like this:

```
expressApp.use((req, res, next) => {
  const language = req.get('language') || 'en_GB';
  logger.info('language:' + language);
  this._languageModule.setLanguage(language);
  frontend = this._languageModule.insertSIDs(frontend);
  logger.info(frontend);
  next();
});

expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../frontend/dist')));
```

the HTML will not be served modified.

Comment: You should not call expressApp.use multiple times with the same arguments and especially not in a request handler, also you want to implement your own request handler function that reads the file, and edits the file you need.

Comment: So what approach do you think of - modifying the html before serving it? Maybe without using middleware function at all?

Comment: It depends if you have to modify the response for each request?

Comment: No only for the core route = '/'. And even then - only one time.

Comment: What do you mean by core route? If you have to modify the response for a client at least one then do the modification in the response handler. If your files can stay static and you only have to update them once (during building the application for example) then implement it in your build tool? I'll post an answer in a second

Comment: Thanks! I welcome any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should write your own middleware that handles the modification of the files. Here's an example not tested. But it's rough. It's based on the `express.static` function

```
const fs = require("fs");
var parseUrl = require('parseurl')

app.use((req, res, next) => {

    var originalUrl = parseUrl.original(req)
    var path = parseUrl(req).pathname

     // make sure redirect occurs at mount
    if (path === '/' && originalUrl.pathname.substr(-1) !== '/') {
        path = ''
    }

    // We only answer to GET 
    if (req.method !== 'GET' && req.method !== 'HEAD') {
        return next()
    }

    let path = path;
    fs.exists(path, (exists) => {
        if(!exists)
        {
            // file don't exists skip this middleware
            return next();
        }
        fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
            if (err)
            {
                // Can't send the file skip this middle ware
                return next();
            }


            // Do whatever you need with the file here?
            // ...


            // Setup mime type of the file
            res.setHeader("content-type", "text/html");
            // send the client the modified html
            res.send(data);
        });
        console.log(exists ? 'it\'s there' : 'no passwd!');
    });
});
```

For the original source please take a look at this github page:
https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js